# unable to run python script as windows service using multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, service

I have a python app that has 2 thread,
1)flask app with some routes
2)python script that runs repeatedly every X secs
my service code looks like this :

```
class Service():
    main = threading.Thread(target=Mains)
    server = threading.Thread(target=lambda: app.run(port=9999, use_reloader=False))

    def stop(self):
        """Stop the service"""
        self.running = False
        while self.running == False:
            exit()

    def run(self):
        """Main service loop. This is where work is done!"""
        self.running = True
        while self.running:
            logging.info("START MAIN THREAD")
            self.main.start()
            logging.info("START SERVER THREAD")
            self.server.start()
            servicemanager.LogInfoMsg("Service running...")


class MyServiceFramework(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = 'Python Service'
    _svc_display_name_ = 'Python Service...'
    _svc_description_ = 'lorem ipsum'

    def SvcStop(self):
        """Stop the service"""
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        self.service_impl = Service()
        self.service_impl.stop()
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOPPED)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        """Start the service; does not return until stopped"""
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_START_PENDING)
        self.service_impl = Service()
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_RUNNING)
        # Run the service
        self.service_impl.run()


def init():
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        servicemanager.Initialize()
        servicemanager.PrepareToHostSingle(MyServiceFramework)
        servicemanager.StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()
    else:
        win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(MyServiceFramework)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    init()
```

after I compiling my python script to '.exe' file and the install process works fine and the service appears in the "Windows Service Managar", when I trying to start the service it throws an error:

```
A service process other than the one launched by the Service Control Manager connected when starting the Python Service service.  The Service Control Manager launched process 6904 and process 2644 connected instead.
```

in the logs file I noticed the app keeps running although the service is not running according to windows service control manager, so I try to kill this app, and every time I wanted to kill the app I used TAKKILL /im Service.exe /F it shows to process.
my idea is I have a wrong service-multithreading configuration, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The reason was I started the threads every time when I put it inside the while loop, so I tried to use without the while loop:

```
 def run(self):
    self.running = True
        logging.info("START MAIN THREAD")
        self.main.start()
        logging.info("START SERVER THREAD")
        self.server.start()
        servicemanager.LogInfoMsg("Service running...")
```

And it still didn’t work so I changed it to still run inside of a while loop, but the threads will start only once.

```
 def run(self):
        logging.info("START MAIN THREAD")
        self.main.start()
        logging.info("START SERVER THREAD")
        self.server.start()
        self.running = True
        while self.running:  
          servicemanager.LogInfoMsg("Service running...")
```

And it works out 
It’s make sense why it didn’t work without the loop, running program as a service means that it suppose to be running all the time, in a loop.